# Query Influxdb based on tags?

Tags: influxdb

I have started playing around with Influxdb v0.13 and I have some dummy values in my test db where `id` is a tag and `value` is a field:

```
> SELECT * FROM dummy
name: dummy
--------------
time                    id     value
1468276508161069051     1234    12345
1468276539152853428     613     352
1468276543470535110     613     4899
1468276553853436191     1234    12
```

I get no results returned when I run this query:

```
> SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE id=1234
```

but I do get the following when querying with the field instead:

```
> SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE value=12
name: dummy
--------------
time                    id     value
1468276553853436191     1234    12
```

Am I doing something wrong here? I thought the point of tags were to be queried (since they are indexed and fields are not), but they seem to break my queries.

Comment: I don't have the exact dataset so I am using the runtime measurement to try out. `SELECT * FROM runtime WHERE Frees=59094` runs fine on my machine and I got 1 row back, note it might not work on your machine as there may not be a row with `Frees=59094`. Maybe try enquoting `id` with single quote. Which I doubt it will be any difference since I can evidently see that it is integer.

Comment: @SamuelToh Thanks for the suggestion. Those 4 entries are the entire data set. Quotes didn't seem to do anything as it still returned nothing (double and single on key and/or value).

Comment: @SamuelToh Just kidding? I seem to have missed something because it is working now with single quotes around the tag value. Not sure if I can mark your comment as correct or if you need to submit an answer.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I will post an answer for this so that other people can just scroll down quickly for a solution.

Comment: I made some research myself and it turns out there is a line in their documentation that states tag key and values are all string in influxdb and that explains why you need enquoting. See my answer for link.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It appears that Influx will treat every tag key and value we insert as string and this is evidently shown in their official documentation.

See: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/guides/writing_data/

> When writing points, you must specify an existing database in the db
>   query parameter. See the HTTP section on the Write Syntax page for a
>   complete list of the available query parameters. The body of the POST
>   - we call this the Line Protocol - contains the time-series data that you wish to store. They consist of a measurement, tags, fields, and a
>   timestamp. InfluxDB requires a measurement name. **Strictly speaking,
>   tags are optional but most series include tags to differentiate data
>   sources and to make querying both easy and efficient. Both tag keys
>   and tag values are strings.**

Note: the text in bold.

Hence to filter by tag key value - the query must be enquoted.

**Example**:

`SELECT * FROM dummy WHERE id='1234'`